# How convert a method to Asynchronous method

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asynchronous

I have a method in C# that is using Entity Framework 6 for Database part. This method is returning all the Years. I wonder how I can convert method to the Asynchronous method.

```
  public override IEnumerable<Year> GetYears()
    {
        return creditApplicationsContext.Years.ToList();
    }
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the [ToListAsync()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn220262(v=vs.113).aspx) method with the async/await keywords?

```
public override async Task<IEnumerable<Year>> GetYears()
{
    return await creditApplicationsContext.Years.ToListAsync();
}
```

And you should probably rename it accordingly:

```
public override async Task<IEnumerable<Year>> GetYearsAsync()
```

Comment: Nice.  You might want to add a note that the rename will affect the base method definition.  Perhaps an additional override? One sync and one async? +1